# filter array entity is not key value coding-compliant

Tags: objective-c

My app seems to crash at this line:

```
id obj = [[@[self] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[BPDObject predicateObjectsThatNeedToBeSynced]] firstObject];
```

with this error:

```
[<Contact 0x17049b580> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity (null) is not key value coding-compliant for the key "m_last_modified".
```

But I can't seem to understand how the error message relates to the code? Could the error be related to a thread other than main?

Comment: An exception breakpoint will tell you the line for sure, but there's ample reason to suspect the posted line.  It's a pretty odd thing, isn't it, to put self in an array and then filter it?   Do you just want to apply some test (determined by BPDObject) to self?  `predicate evaluateWithObject:` does that.

Comment: Remember that the object (self) must be KVC compliant for every key path mentioned in the predicate, for example: m_last_modified.

Comment: So what could be happening is that the property for that key isn't set, specifically the m_last_modified property? Why would it be saying 'the entity null'?

Comment: Yeah, that's mysterious.

Comment: (posting frmo diff account) Here's the predicate im using: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SELF.m_last_modified > SELF.updated_at) || ((SELF.updated_at = nil) AND (SELF.m_last_modified != nil))"];

How could it be possible that SELF in this instance is nil?

Comment: What is the class of `self` in `@[self]`? Is `Contact` a subclass of `NSManagedObject`?

Comment: Yes and yes, self is an instance of the ```Contact``` class which is a subclass of ```NSManagedObject```

Comment: The entity of this Contact is nil. I've seen this before but I can't remember what caused it. It was something simple like a new Contact which isn't added to a context yet or accessing the Contact from a different thread.

Comment: Interesting if you ever remember what it was then I'd love to know! I don't think it's accessing a contact from a different thread, I went though and made sure all code data operations were performed on the main thread